# TypeError: Cannot set property 'variable' of undefined, when setting this.variable in BeforeEach

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm new to Javascript. I have the following code following exactly per https://stackoverflow.com/a/58785118

```
  describe('tests', () => {
    beforeEach(async () =>
      Promise.resolve('foo').then(result => {
        this.dom = result;
      })
    );

    it('works', () => {
      console.log(this.dom); // => foo
    });
  });
```

When running the test, it complaints

```
1) tests
       "before each" hook for "works":
     TypeError: Cannot set property 'dom' of undefined
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Why not do `let output; beforeEach( (done) => Promise...then( (result) => output = result; ) )` and then check `output` for validity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to remove the usage of `this` and declare a variable in the scope of the `describe()` callback:

```
  describe('tests', () => {
    let dom;
    beforeEach(async () =>
      Promise.resolve('foo').then(result => {
        dom = result;
      })
    );

    it('works', () => {
      console.log(dom); // => foo
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in your promise `then` and in test `it` callback functions.

> Before arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value
>   based on how the function was called:
>
> - A new object in the case of a constructor.
> - undefined in strict mode function calls.
> - The base object if the function was called as an "object method".

So the problem with your code is that in scope of test's callback arrow function `this` is refers to parent scope of `describe` block.

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`. The this value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not
>   present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this
>   from its enclosing scope.

As one option you can define variable at parent scope at `describe` block and use it in `beforeAll` and `it` callback.